# Displaying styled text in a text component

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way to put styled text in a text component, similar to JTextPane in Swing, in Codename One?

Based on looking at the docs, the only way that I can see to display styled text is to use a native BrowserComponent with an HTML file. However, I would need it in a component with a paint() method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WebBrowser but you can't do this in a component with paint(). You could use the deprecated HTMLComponent which allows painting and accepts a very rudimentary form of HTML but that's probably not the best approach...

If you just need display and not editing just create a flow layout container and place all the elements within. Styled labels, images etc. Then place it in a layered layout and place on top the component where you would like to draw with paint.

If you need editing then [Steve Hannah](https://github.com/shannah/) implemented an HTML editor component using the web browser API in Codename One.